# Chrome Console does not take line commands

Tags: android, cordova, google-chrome-devtools

I have been using Chrome to debug a mobile application that I am working on, but lately I am unable to give commands like `console.log('test')`, or debug variables, for example: if I typed `Array_Person` I would get something like

```
[Object,Object]
  >0:Object
  >1:Object
```

And if i expand the object i would get the data inside. Now it doesnt.

Now for some reason every time i try to debug my device application, no matter what i type, it works like i am typing on notepad [image: DevTools example]

It affects only my device debugger, if i try to debug a website it works as usual

What I have already tried:
- Close then open Google Chrome
- Uninstall and reinstall Google Chrome
- Reboot computer
- Recompile the mobile application

I expected to be able to open the details of the Array, as I want to debug the content of an array.

Obs: I am new here, so if my question does not fit this site, do tell me where should i send this question.